# Stack behavior when adding new thread

Tags: java, c++, multithreading

What happens to stack when we create new thread?
If it gets on the top of the stack, so how is it a thread?! If it doesn't get on the top of the thread, so how the program know where to continue it's job?

Comment: Each thread gets its own, independent stack. I'm not sure I understand the last question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So can a program handle two or more stacks at same time?! If yes, how? (I mean how it gets track of new calls on different stacks at same time.)

Comment: Yes it can. Or rather, the operating system does. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)

Comment: There is context switching per thread, which includes switching the stack pointer.

Comment: Why are there both Java and C++ tags? Please choose one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each thread gets it's own stack. So if the initial thread creates a second thread, then this does not affect the stack of the first thread. And the second thread will have it's own stack. So in that process two independant stacks exist - one per thread. But each thread will only use it's own thread. The operating system sees both threads - and takes care that the proper stack is being set/used when switching from one thread to another.

Comment: Actually, since it's the same process, the first thread is not invisible from the other.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis That's right. What is your suggestion for a technically correct and also simple/understandable wording? Besides: I do not know of a standard C++ way to get the stack of another process.

Comment: I think that your answer is ok, just to not unnecessarily confuse the OP.  I just put the comment here to give a clue to someone that is more advanced.

Comment: @WernerHenze It is quite common in C to pass one thread the address of an object on another thread's stack. Stacks are process resources that are accessible to all threads in the process.